# Does anyone know of an HDMI splitter that strips HDCP 2.2?

Tags: usb, hdmi, video

I am working on a project that requires the use of an HDMI USB capture device, but because of HDCP 2.2, all captured video is just showing up black. I have read that some HDMI splitters can strip HDCP 1.4, but I am yet to find anything that can verifiably strip a signal of HDCP 2.2. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HDCP [2.2 has been broken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-bandwidth_Digital_Content_Protection#HDCP_v2.2,_v2.1_and_v2.0_breach) but any question about circumventing anti-piracy measures may not be something people will be willing to answer on this site.